# SQL query showing results Year to month per month

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database with every action my users have done timestamped which looks like this:
`user_id` ; `action` ; `creation_date`

I want to assess the number of active users over time.
I can see the number of users that are active per week (count (distinct user_id)), but I want to know the number of users that have been active since the beginning of the year to each week like this :

-number of users active week1
-number of users active week1 or week 2
-number of users active week1, week2 or week 3
etc

I can't just add the active users each week since they come back so if I did some would be counted double.

For now I can do it per week with this query:

```
SELECT count(distinct uca.user_id)
FROM DATABASE
WHERE (extract(week from uca.creation_date)) <= 9
```

How can I have a single query that gives me this for every week ?

(sorry this was too long I realise I wanted to be extra clear)

Thank you!

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a subquery.  Your sample query is a bit confusing (table alias `uca` is not defined, you are only extracting the week and not the year).  I think you want something like this:

```
SELECT year(uca.creation_date), week(uca.creation_date),
       count(distinct uca.user_id) as WEEK_users,
       (select count(distinct uca2.user_id)
        from database uca2
        where year(uca2.creation_date) = year(uca.creation_date) and
              week(uca2.creation_date) <= week(uca.creation_date)
       ) as YTD_users
FROM DATABASE uca
GROUP BY year(uca.creation_date), week(uca.creation_date)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid the correlated subquery in Gordon Linoff's answer might be executed for each line of the *input*, which is inefficient. Here is a way equivalent to executing it only once for each line of the *output*:

`SELECT
  year(creation_date),
  week(creation_date),
  count(distinct user_id) as YTD_users
FROM uca
JOIN (SELECT year(creation_date) as year, week(creation_date) as week
      FROM uca
      GROUP BY year(creation_date), week(creation_date)
     ) AS weeks
ON year(creation_date) = year AND week(creation_date) <= week`